# How to display two lists in a Django template?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to both django and python.

This in an example code i made up to illustrate my problem:

## Models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='book_subby')
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publishers)


class Publishers(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='publisher_subby')
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    book_publisher = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

## View

```
def book_list(request):
    books = Book.objects.filter(submitted_by=request.user, submitted_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('submitted_date')
    books_by_publisher = 
    return render(request, 'book/list_books.html', {
        'books': books 
        })
```

## Template list_books.html

```
{% for book in books %}
    <ul> {{ book.book_publisher }}
    <li> {{book.book_title }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This displays:

Publisher X
* Book A
Publisher Y
* Book B
Publisher X
* Book C
Publisher Y
* Book D

I want to display:
Publisher X
* Book A
* Book C

Publisher Y
* Book B
* Book D

I tried doing multiple for loops in the template, but couldn't make it work.
I would appreciate it alot if someone could nudge me in the right direction on how to solve this. 
Thanks, Andrea

Comment: As a first step you're going to have to group your books by publisher on the server side.

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking of ways to do this in views. Any tips to nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: See below.  You want to group on the server :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

## Models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='book_subby')
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publishers, related_name='books')

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['submitted_date'] # To keep this sorted by this field
```

## View

```
def book_list(request):
    publishers_with_books = Publishers.objects.prefetch_related('books').filter(submitted_by=request.user, books__isnull=False, books__submitted_date__lte=timezone.now())
    return render(request, 'book/list_books.html', {
        'publishers': publishers_with_books 
        })
```

## Template list_books.html

```
{% for publisher in publishers %}
    <ul> {{ book.book_publisher }}
        {% for book in publisher.books.all %}
            <li> {{book.book_title }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps to you ;).

Comment: Since it does the job, `publisher.books.all` will hit the database for each publisher which in turn may cause serious performance issues if total number of publishers is considerably high.

Comment: It is just a solution more, and that can of course be improved @ozgur.